# background-image doesn't work with Chromes

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image

I have a background-image which appears well on Firefox but does not appear on Google Chrome at all. I don't understand ... Thank you very much.

edit : I see that I am told that the answer is already elsewhere but no. I don't have add block so it's not the same problem. Thank you anyway.

CSS :

```
    #section2{
        background: url(../images/references.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        position:relative;
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div id="section2">

</div>
```

Comment: Probably obvious, but have you tried clearing your Chrome browser's cache?

Comment: Thank you Christopher. Yes I do and I tested on another computer and it's the same thing

Comment: Do you have any report of a 404 error in your Chrome's Development Tools' Network tab?

Comment: Thank you yunzen. No, I have that : https://i.imgur.com/tDsbtie.jpg

Comment: This is not the dev tools network tab, that's just the CSS styles for an element. Please check your network tab, there it shows you which image is requested and what the status for that image is (maybe it's a 404- not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the background-image: property

```
#section2{
        background-image: url(../images/references.png); 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        position:relative;
    }
```

Comment: Thak you very much It's working ! I thought I had already tried :o

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you can see your image on firefox with the code you show us.

Div size can't adjust to background-image size. Meaning that if your div has a height and width of 0, we won't be able to see background-image.

If you add content to your div or width and height in CSS, you'll see the image appear.

```css
 #section2 {
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no height / No content in the div so you sould not see anything.
Code is fine anyway

```
#section 2 {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Add this to ur css